# How can i create a document for if there is none? (MongoDB + Discord.js v14)

Tags: discord.js

So basically i want to create a document for a certain user when a moderator uses a command:

```
                if (!entry) {
                    let document = await new infractions({ userID: user.id, guildID: interaction.guild.id, mute: 0 })
                    console.log('member didnt have an entry so one was created')
                    document.save()
                }
                entry.mute += 1
                entry.save();
```

Now even if it does print ('member didnt have an entry so one was created') the `entry.mute` just doesnt work.

Here is the error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'mute')`

Im guessing this has something to do with `entry.mute` but i dont know what i did wrong here.

If i missed out on any info you need to help me please let me know in the comments below. Thanks!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but just because you create the document in your `if`, the `entry` variable isn't magically assigned any value

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is you're creating a variable within a scope and then trying to use it *outside* the scope (and by another name, even).

I'm assuming that `entry` is meant to be `undefined` if there is no document and an instance of `infractions` otherwise.

What's currently happening is this:

```js
if (!entry) { // Enter scope
  let document = /* ... */ // Create variable within scope
  console.log('There was no entry for this member, so one was created.')
  document.save()
} // Exit scope; variable `document` is gone

entry.mute += 1 // The value of entry was never changed; this is still undefined.
```

The behavior you want could easily be solved by changing the value of `entry` within the if statement. Here:

```js
if (!entry) {
  entry = await new infractions({ userID: user.id, guildID: interaction.guild.id, mute: 0 })
  console.log('member didnt have an entry so one was created')
  // Don't save here because we'll do that later no matter what
}
entry.mute += 1
entry.save(); // Save here. If we save in the if statement, we'll just save twice for no reason.
```

Again, I'm *assuming* that `entry` is supposed to be an instance of `infractions`. This example will create a new instance and assign it to `entry` if `entry` was previously `undefined`, `null` (as it is here), or any falsy value.

What I'm guessing has happened is that `entry` is fetched from MongoDB, but if no such entry exists, then `entry` is assigned `null`. When you get the document from MongoDB, the document you get is only the value of the document at the time of getting it (so `entry` was null); any modifications or new documents (`document`) made after getting the document will not be reflected in old variables like `entry`, and so `entry` remains `null` even after the document is made. I can assume all of this because your error states that `entry` is `null` rather than some "reference" to a document.

TL;DR, if `entry` is `null`, then `entry` will still be null unless you change the variable itself.